# Is it possible to move the right-click context menu on the taskbar in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

In Windows 7, when you right click an item on the taskbar, you get a context menu directly above it:

[image]

When you do the same thing in Windows 10, the context menu appears over the top of the taskbar, as opposed to right on the task:

[image]

I find this slows down productivity in two ways. First, I have to move the mouse farther. But second and more important, it's not always clear you've selected the correct task, especially as you're moving the mouse towards the menu. I've been paranoid I'm about to accidentally close the wrong window a few times. Is there any way to force the context menu to appear directly over the task in Windows 10?

Comment: I'm not certain about the answer to your question, but you might consider putting your taskbar on the right or left side of the screen.  Right-click Taskbar, unlock, click and drag the taskbar to the side, right-click, lock.  See if that will work for you.

Comment: Yeah that theoretically could improve things by forcing a single column. But I have a three-monitor setup with all three in portrait mode, so I can't afford to give up any more width on my main screen. Good idea though generally speaking.